# Split csv file only for first 4 delimiters then drop the rest for the line

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am trying to read in a csv file line by line and only capture the first `4` fields per line, the rest should be dropped. Here is my input:

[image]

```
1   DateTime    Temp
2   02/11/2021 0:00 35
3   04/11/2021 0:00 32
4   05/11/2021 0:00 34
5   06/11/2021 0:00 28
6   07/11/2021 0:00 27.5 , 25
7   08/11/2021 0:00 25.6
8   09/11/2021 0:00 23.7, 
9   10/11/2021 0:00 21.8
```

So line `6` and `8` will have more columns, however I would like to drop the `...,25` and `...,` for line `6` and `8` respectively.

I would like to get the following output:

[image]

Here is the code I tried to use in a loop:

```
while True:
        line=f.readline()
        line=line.strip()
        if line == '': Break
        line=line.split(',', 2)
        entries.append(line)
print(entries)
```

It does not however produce this somehow.

Comment: Can you show your CSV file in pure text format

Comment: @BrutusForcus I added the text information as requested

Comment: It looks more like you want the first `3` columns? Instead of `line=line.split(',', 2)` you could use `line=line.split(',')[:3]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
df["Temp"] = df["Temp"].apply(lambda item:int(str(item).split(",")[0].strip()))
df.to_csv(file_path)
```

use pandas to read csv and change Temp Tag and save to csv

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, not exactly what I am after. I would like to split the one line as per delimiter and only a specific number of times. So the the import is file, the challenge is how to deal with the DataFarame line by line and  only split a specific number of delimiters and drop the rest